# ELSE statement running one time per ".each" element

Tags: jquery

I have a form, sent trough Ajax. First it checks if all inputs are filled (if not, applies style, and the `msg()` function makes error emerge), and if they are filled, stores data and sends it trough Ajax:

```
$(document).on('click','.accepEditedData',function(){
    obj=$(this);
    sectionEdit=obj.attr('data-section');
    newInputs=$('input[data-sectionC='+sectionEdit+']');    
    newInputs.each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() === ""){
            msg('error','Por favor, rellena todos los campos, o cancela la edición de tu información.');
            $(this).css('border-bottom','2px solid red').css('color','red');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            if(obj.hasClass('updateInfoBasic')){
                name=$("input[name='us_name']").val();
                tlf=$("input[name='us_tlf']").val();
                mail=$("input[name='us_mail']").val();
                $.post('../actions/updateInfoBasic.php',{us_name:name, us_mail:mail,us_tlf:tlf}).success(
                    function(){  
                        msg("success","Tu información básica ha sido actualizada");
                });
            }

        }

    });
});
```

I have the next issue: ELSE statement runs one time per each element stored on `newInputs` variable.

When the first IF statement checks 3 inputs, the ELSE statement runs 3 times (including both its ajax call and its `msg('success','...');` function. And the same happens with 4, 6, etc... the total inputs are checked trough `.each`, the total times the ELSE is executed.

Theorically, if all inputs are filled, the ELSE statement should only run once.

Comment: Have you checked what is the value of `$(this).val()` on each iteration? maybe it's not `""`?

Comment: Oh... I checked it before and it worked. Now I must have changed s.thing, even when there's something without value, goes to the ELSE statement.

Comment: Are all `input` elements being selected at `newInputs=$('input[data-sectionC='+sectionEdit+']');` at `click` ? , not only `'.accepEditedData'` `inputs` ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: @Biomehanika What is expected result of `if(obj.hasClass('updateInfoBasic'))`? Is requirement for statement within `else` to be called at most _once_ ? , only if all `input` element values are _not_ `""` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) , [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
$(document).on('click','.accepEditedData',function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    var sectionEdit = obj.attr('data-section');
    var newInputs = $('input[data-sectionC='+sectionEdit+']');
    var check = newInputs.get().some(function(el, i) {
      return el.value === ""
    });

    if (check) {
      msg('error','Por favor, rellena todos los campos, o cancela la edición de tu información.');
      newInputs.filter(function() {
        return this.value === ""
      }).css('border-bottom','2px solid red').css('color','red');
    } else {
       if (obj.hasClass('updateInfoBasic')) {
         var name = $("input[name='us_name']").val();
         var tlf = $("input[name='us_tlf']").val();
         var mail = $("input[name='us_mail']").val();
         $.post('../actions/updateInfoBasic.php',{us_name:name, us_mail:mail,us_tlf:tlf})
         .then(function success() {  
           msg("success","Tu información básica ha sido actualizada");
         }, function error(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
         });
        }
    }
});
```